# function returns previous value

Tags: python, callback, return

I want to get the users input as a number, check its validity and return it. If the number is invalid, I wish to repeat the input process. However if I type:

1. `"5b"`
2. `"50.4"`

The function doesn't return `50.4`. Instead it returns `5.0`, as the ***remainder*** of the first function call is executed. How can I fix the above issue, to only get `50.4`?

```
def inputGoal ():
    goalFiltered = ""
    print ('1: ' + str(goalFiltered))
    goal = input("Input number: ")

    for char in goal:
        matched = False
        for sign in comparator:
            if (sign == char):
                matched = True
                if (char != ','):
                    goalFiltered += sign
                elif (char == ','):
                    goalFiltered += '.'
        if (matched == False):
            print ("Please repeat input, valid characters are: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 , .")
            inputGoal()
            #return
    goalFiltered = float(goalFiltered)
    return (goalFiltered)
```

The comparator variable is:

```
comparator = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',',','.']
```

Comment: In your recursive call, use `return inputGoal()` instead of just `inputGoal()`.

Comment: @smarx **thank you, it works!** Mind explaining, why this stops the **remainder** from executing and why the remainder got executed in the first place, before introducing `return`. Please write an official answer, so I can accept it for future readers

Comment: Since you didn't have a `return`, the code just kept executing after doing the recursive call (and throwing out its return value). Once it finished the loop, it ran `goalFiltered = float(goalFiltered)` and `return goalFiltered`, and so you got the result of applying `float` to whatever characters matched your list.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, I think you can just do this:

```
while True:
    ask = input("Input the number:\t") #The \t just puts a tab so it looks nice
    if ask == float(ask):
        break
    else:
        print("The number is incorrect. Try again.")
        continue
```

Comment: The `continue` doesn't seem to be doing anything here.